# automatically update image when new one uploaded javascript

Tags: javascript, html, ejs, cloudinary

I want to be able to update the image that I see when I upload a new one to the database. I am using Cloudinary, so as soon as I upload to Cloudinary using the widget, I get a unique url, which I can get, but I cannot display the new updated image on page. here's what I got:

```
    <div class="image"style="background: url('<%= ogImgUrl %>') center;
            width: 50%;
            height: 100%;
            display:block;background-size: 75%; background-repeat: no-repeat;
       border-radius: 8px 0 0 8px;">
 <button id="upload_widget" class="button">Upload Product Image</button>
    </div>
        
<form method="GET" action="/editProduct2">
    <!-- submit image -->

 <!-- submit image end -->
 <input type="hidden" name="url" id="url" value="<%= ogImgUrl %>" readonly>
     
      <button id="submitButton" type="submit">SUBMIT CHANGES</button>

</form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
      
               

              <script src="https://widget.cloudinary.com/v2.0/global/all.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
             
              <script type="text/javascript">  
              var myWidget = cloudinary.createUploadWidget({
                cloudName: 'xxx', 
                uploadPreset: 'ld3l7evv'}, (error, result) => { 
                  if (!error && result && result.event === "success") { 
                    console.log('Done! Here is the image info: ', result.info); 
                    console.log(result.info.secure_url)
                    var result_url = result.info.secure_url;
                    console.log("result url is " + result_url)
                    document.getElementById("url").value = result_url;
                  }
                }
              )
             
              document.getElementById("upload_widget").addEventListener("click", function(){
                myWidget.open();
             
                }, false);

               
              </script>
```

so I show the current image from the db here: `<div class="image"style="background: url('<%= ogImgUrl %>') center;`
but now I want to update that image with the new one I upload using the Cloudinary widget. keep in mind as soon as I upload the photo, I get a unique url for that image, so if there is someway to update the original photo and then show the updated one, that would be great. thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update existing image, you can specify the same `public_id` during the upload. You may also want to specify `invalidate: true`. This will invalidate any CDN caches to make sure you are getting the latest version.

Since you are using upload preset, you can also specify if you want to use the original filename, allow/disallow public id.

I suggest to check Cloudinary [Upload API](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_upload_api_reference#upload_method) to check what's the required and possible parameters you can pass during upload call.